# put the find command in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

The following command works fine in a CMD window. It lists directories that contains the word "NOTE" but not "NOTES".

`dir c:\myfiles\mydirectories /s /b /ad |find "NOTE" | find "NOTES" /v`

When I put the command in a batch file, CMD complains `invalid switch -v`.

`dir c:\myfiles\mydirectories /s /b /ad ^|find "NOTE" ^|find "NOTES" /v`

What did I do wrong? Thanks.

This is on Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you:

1. Escaping pipes when you put this in a batch file as a command?
   If so, don't escape the pipes.

   ```
   dir c:\myfiles\mydirectories /s /b /ad |find "NOTE" |find "NOTES" /v
   ```
2. Having the search invokes within a sub-shell?
   If so, retain escape characters on the pipes.
   I mean something like:

   ```
   for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir c:\myfiles\mydirectories /s /b /ad ^|find "NOTE" ^|find "NOTES" /v') do echo Something
   ```
3. Having your command saved in a batch file which is invoked in a sub-shell?
   If so, discard the escape characters.
   I mean:

   ```
   for /f "delims=" %%a in ('call <path to batch file containing your command>') do echo Something
   ```
4. If none of the above apply, is your error showing up when this line is part of a larger batch file? If so, can you please share it entirely?

Answer (score 4):

with `findstr` you need only one pipe:

```
dir c:\myfiles\mydirectories /s /b /ad|findstr "\<NOTE\>"
```

or with a for loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "c:\myfiles\mydirectories" /s /b /ad^|findstr "\<NOTE\>"') do echo %%~a
```

`\<` is the Regex for the start of a word
`\>` is the Regex for the end of a word
see `help findstr` for more help.